# Failed to configure Identity Server 5.0.0 as API Key Manager

Tags: wso2

I followed document to configure Identity Server 5.0.0 as API(1.80) Key Manager - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager, and log displayed exceptions when startup after installed API Key Manager feature in Identity server. The exceptions are as following:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.RegistryConfigLoader} -  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.WSDLIndexer is not found in classpath. Please check whether the class is exported in your OSGI bundle. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.RegistryConfigLoader}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.WSDLIndexer
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.RegistryConfigLoader.<init>(RegistryConfigLoader.java:132)
...

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Could not instantiate Solr client {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\wso2\wso2is-5.0.0\solr\data\index\_7.fnm (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1068)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:579)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.<init>(SolrClient.java:90)
```

...

Can anyone help? I would be very gratefull.

Comment: Did you copy the registry.xml+apimanager.xml of AM 1.8.0 to IS 5.0.0 after installing the features?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I can find the jar file including WSDLIndexer.class under IS 5.0.0 folder. it's very weird.

Comment: Hello did you find a solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the issue.  When installing the Key Manager feature in this article and installing the WSO2 Identity Manager Service pack after the Key Manager, there are two files in the /repository/components/plugins directory:

org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing_4.2.1.jar
org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing_4.2.2.jar

I resolved this issue by removing the 4.2.1 jar version and leaving the 4.2.2 jar version.  After doing so, no errors were encountered.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brian. This issue is fixed in latest version.